# Expect script not sending commands after successful ssh login

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

When launching the following script, the ssh login succeeds, and I'm able to  interact, but it doesn't send the `cd folder` command. Is my `expect "$"` command useful at all if I know for sure that this is the first command I want to send, and how can the `cd folder` command be sent?

Here's the short expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no host@exemple.com
expect "password"
send "mypassword\r"
expect "$"
send "cd folder\r"
interact
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `expect` a more specific shell prompt.

According to expect's manual:

> Note  that in many editors, the `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of lines respectively. However, because expect is *not line oriented*, these characters match the *beginning and end of the data* (as opposed to lines) currently *in the expect matching buffer*.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your SSH keys using [`ssh-keygen`](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/) (or like [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)), and ask the server administrator to add your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server. Then you will be able to log in to the remote machine without specifying the password. Otherwise, anyone who has read access to the script would be able to access the remote server *on your behalf!* There is a [good discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38737/ssh-login-with-clear-text-password-as-a-parameter) regarding this problem.

With the configured keys, you can simply

```
ssh user@exemple.com -- 'cd folder; # whatever'
```

or, using the [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash -
ssh -tt user@host <<'EOC'
cd folder
# do something else
exit
EOC
```

Note, the first `-t` option forces pseudo-terminal allocation. Multiple `-t` options force *tty* allocation, even if `ssh` has no local *tty*.