# Expect: Extract negative number from command's output

Tags: expect

I'm using expect script to execute a command and want to extract a number from the output which I intend to use in the script later. If I just use the following command in my script

```
$expect_out(buffer)
```

I get the following which has the command as well as the actual output

```
# some_command | awk '{print $2}'
-2520
```

Based on the examples I saw on internet I modified my script to use regex to extract just the number, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
set prompt "(\\\$|#) $"

... Login code goes here

expect -re $prompt
send "some_command | awk '{print \$2}'\r" --> Prints a negative number (not floating) i.e -2520
expect -re {"^-[0-9]\d*"}
set num $expect_out(0,string)
puts "Result : $num"

send "exit\r"
```

For some reason I can't extract the number -2520 from the buffer. The output I get is:

```
# Result : #
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need remove `"` from regexp: `expect -re {^-?\d+}`

Comment: @komar — `{^-?\d+}` would not work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498940/expect-script-not-sending-commands-after-successful-ssh-login/40499422#40499422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoul write like this:

```
expect -re {[\r\n](-?[0-9]+)}
set num $expect_out(1,string)
```

Example:

```
[STEP 101] # cat foo.exp
set re_PS1 {bash-[.0-9]+[#$] $}

spawn bash --norc
expect -re $re_PS1

send "[lindex $argv 0]\r"
expect {
    -re {[\r\n](-?[0-9]+)} {
        set num $expect_out(1,string)
        exp_continue
    }
    -re $re_PS1
}

send "exit\r"
expect eof

puts "result: $num"
[STEP 102] # expect foo.exp 'expr 0 - 12345'
spawn bash --norc
bash-4.4# expr 0 - 12345
-12345
bash-4.4# exit
exit
result: -12345
[STEP 103] # expect foo.exp 'expr 12345'
spawn bash --norc
bash-4.4# expr 12345
12345
bash-4.4# exit
exit
result: 12345
[STEP 104] #
```